# mySQL error 1064 on Forward Engineering

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Using mySQL workbench, i created an EER diagram and populated it with appropriate data for a class I am in. This is the sample of the generated code that creates the issue:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bhk13`.`person` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bhk13`.`person` (
  `per_id` MEDIUMINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
  `per_fname` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `per_lname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `per_city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `per_state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `per_street` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `per_zip` INT NOT NULL,
  `per_phone` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `per_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `per_ssn` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `per_gender` ENUM('m', 'f', 'o') NOT NULL,
  `per_dob` DATE NOT NULL,
  `per_is_emp` ENUM('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
  `per_is_alm` ENUM('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
  `per_is_stu` ENUM('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
  `per_note` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`per_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

when I attempt to forward engineer the database, it generates the following error:

```
Thread started
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VIRTUAL,
  `per_fname` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `per_lname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NUL' at line 2
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bhk13`.`person` (
          `per_id` MEDIUMINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
          `per_fname` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
          `per_lname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
          `per_city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `per_state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
          `per_street` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `per_zip` INT NOT NULL,
          `per_phone` BIGINT NOT NULL,
          `per_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          `per_ssn` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `per_gender` ENUM('m', 'f', 'o') NOT NULL,
          `per_dob` DATE NOT NULL,
          `per_is_emp` ENUM('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
          `per_is_alm` ENUM('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
          `per_is_stu` ENUM('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
          `per_note` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`per_id`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

What is causing this issue and how can I fix it? All of the data is consistent

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using. I'm assuming 5.7, but just want to make sure

Comment: `per_id` MEDIUMINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,` shouldn't you have an **`expression`** for the `GENERATED FIELD`  such as  `AS ('something')`?